# Centre of the Universe

Tags: universe, big-bang-theory

Why shouldn't the original singularity of the big bang happen to be the centre of the Universe? Assume that the universe is expanding isotropically with a constant speed.

Comment: Hi Jack and welcome to Astronomy on StackExchange.  Your question will likely be flagged as a 'duplicate' question (and closed.)  I can appreciate your curiosity... and that's a good thing.  I would encourage you to use the StackExchange search feature and enter 'center of the universe' to find many excellent answers as this question has been asked and answered several times.

Answer (score 2):

(I can't comment)- See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point

TLDR, The big bang happened everywhere in the universe at the same time, because it was the universe. The top answer goes more in depth.